# Write as a product $\cos x+\sqrt3\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry

Write as a product $$\cos x+\sqrt3\sin x$$
The authors' solution goes as:

$$\cos x+\sqrt3\sin x=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac12\cos x+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin x\right)=\dfrac12\left(\cos60^\circ\cos x+\sin60^\circ\sin x\right)\\=\dfrac12\cos(x-60^\circ)$$ I don't see how are $\cos x+\sqrt3\sin$ and $\dfrac12\left(\dfrac12\cos x+\dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\sin x\right)$ equal. They are clearly not?!

Comment: Replace the first $1/2$ with $2$. Probably a typo in your textbook.

Comment: Indeed they are not. A factor of 4 is missing on the outside. The important part was to change the inner coefficients to $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ since then their sums of squares adds to 1, so they can be represented as a cosine and sine.

Comment: @bjorn93, so the answer is actually $2\cos(x-60^\circ)$. We can write it also as $2\cos(60^\circ-x),$ right?

Comment: The author's solution (even when corrected as comments direct) is not a product. That is, the answer has *not* written the starting expression as a product. [unless one counts $2f(x)$ as a product, but then can write it as a product in many trivial ways.]

Comment: @Hipo that's correct